# Google People API does not return an emailAddress for people/me

Tags: google-people-api

I'm using the [Google API Console Tool](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) tool, and when I do the query

```
resourceName: people/me  
personFields: emailAddresses
```

I get the following response:

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/102381120202845324999",
  "etag": "%EgUBCT43LhoMAQIDBAUGBwgJCgsMIgw0eHhmblFCa0Qybz0="
}
```

As you can see, no email address is included. This only happens with one of my gmail accounts. Using another account I would get a response like:

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/104150119553351608999",
  "etag": "%EgUBCT43LhoMAQIDBAUGBwgJCgsMIgxIc2JBaWZXWldGQT0=",
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "verified": true,
        "source": {
        "type": "DOMAIN_PROFILE",
         "id": "104150119553351608710"
        }
     },
     "value": "xx@example.com"
    } 
}
```

Any idea what the cause could be?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem for some of my users, but can't figure out how to reproduce so far.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. We have several domains where this is working totally fine but one where it is not and there is no indication why.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to G Suite.